# Trouble fiixing tumblr images?

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

Images will fit inside post container but will shrink significantly when doing so please help

Here is the link to my blog to look at the code

https://poke--spe.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 200%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```